# Inconsistent theme after installing and removing KDE Desktop

Tags: gnome, kde, themes, budgie

after I have installed the KDE Plasma desktop on my Ubuntu Budgie system, I wanted now to revert to my old Budgie desktop. After I uninstalled the KDE desktop following this [tutorial](https://trendoceans.com/how-to-remove-the-kde-plasma-environment-in-ubuntu/) and resetted the Gnome theme, I noticed that there are a few applications using parts of the old KDE Sweet theme.

All budgie applications dont't have this problem. I also changed the theme in GNOME Tweaks.

Note: The selection color is blue

These pictures show the problems:

[Desktop selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVnOH.png)
[Gnome Software Center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Km2lt.png)
[Glade Designer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PB3tQ.png)
[Geary title bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5W6o1.png)

Comment: This is especially happening with GNOME Apps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting the `~/.gtkrc` (or similar) file and all files and directories matching the pattern `~/.config/*gtkrc*`, all created by Plasma, fixed the issue for me.